# How to make a newline for every 15 spaces with numbers in java

Tags: java, arraylist, output, bluej

I have the following code that finds the prime factors from 1 to the user input. The problem is that the output is in one very long line, I want every 15 numbers to output then go to the next line. How would I do that?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    System.out.println("\nLab1la\n");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the primes upperbond ==>> ");
    final int MAX = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    boolean primes[];
    primes = new boolean[MAX];

    ArrayList<Integer>PrimeFactor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 2; i < MAX + 1 ; i++)
    {
        PrimeFactor.add(i); 
    }

    System.out.println("COMPUTING RIME NUMBERS");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("PRIMES BETWEEN 1 AND " + MAX);

    CompositeNumbers(PrimeFactor);

    for (int value : PrimeFactor)
    {
        System.out.print(value);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

}

public static void CompositeNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> PrimeFactor)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PrimeFactor.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!isPrime(PrimeFactor.get(i)))
        { 
            PrimeFactor.remove(i);
            i--;

        }
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < n +1/2; i++)
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
        {
            return false;

        }
    }
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: Why not just have a counter that increments every time you find a prime, and then whenever it's divisible by 15, go to a new line?

Comment: Yes counter would do it .

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PrimeFactor.size(); i++)
{
    if (i > 0 && i % 15 == 0) System.out.println();
    System.out.print(PrimeFactor.get(i));
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a counter and take a mod of this counter value for 15 and print it in the next line, like below. Like @soong described

```
int counter = 0;
    for (int value : PrimeFactor)
    {
         if(counter % 15 == 0){
             System.out.println();
         }

        System.out.print(value);
        System.out.print(" ");
        counter++;
    }
```